# Show all rows and as specific row in Cassandra's column family

Tags: cassandra, hector

For some reason, I can only use 'cassandra-cli' to do some CQL operations. This is the version I use:

```
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version 1.1.10
```

And the Cassandra version I use is:

```
apache-cassandra-1.1.10
```

I create a keyspace called 'goldenbuck' and a column family called 'holytest' inside that keyspace. Then I insert a row in it using Hector API.

But back to 'cassandra-cli' to check the content of that column family, such output from 'cli' occurs:

```
[default@goldenbuck] SELECT * FROM holytest;
Syntax error at position 7: unexpected "*" for `SELECT * FROM holytest;`.
```

I am pretty sure 'holytest' is there in the 'goldenbuck' keyspace. So what's wrong? How can I get all rows in the 'holytest' and a specific row?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the CLI which is a thrift based tool for interfacing with cassandra. You cant run CQL queries within cassandra-cli. You want to use `cqlsh` instead of the cli, `cql` queries are meant to be executed in the cqlsh shell.

Alternatively, if you do want to use the cli, have a read through the [apache wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli) on the CLI to get started with it.

**On a side note...**
My advice, move to a newer version of cassandra. At-least, 1.2 **but preferably 2.1**, where CQL was getting enough attention and effort making it quite a feature reach querying lang. If you have to use cassandra 1.1 as per requirements, the I'd stick with using thrift purely from a performance and feature standpoint (cql wasn't as advanced in 1.1 as it is now, and much of the documentation might lead to confusion about what you can and can't do).